# Can I save a text file in python without closing it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program in which I would like to be able to view a log file before the program is complete. I have noticed that, in python (2.7 and 3), that `file.write()` does not save the file, `file.close()` does. I don't want to create a million little log files with unique names but I would like to be able to view the updated log file before the program is finished. How can I do this?

Now, to be clear I am scripting using Ansys Workbench (trying to batch some CFX runs). Here's a [link](http://www.padtinc.com/blog/the-focus/workbench-and-excel-part-2-driving-workbench-from-excel-with-python) to a tutorial that shows what I'm talking about. They appear to have wrapped python, and by running the script I can send commands to the various modules. When the script is running there is no console onscreen and it appears to be eating all of the `print` statements, so the only way I can report what's happening is via a file. Also, I don't want to bring a console window up because eventually I will just run the program in batch mode (no interface). But the simulations take a long time to run and I can't wait for the program to finish before checking on what's happening.

Comment: I found open(filename, mode, buffering =0) to be more suitable. Here, if you use 0 for 3rd positional argument, it will flush out the buffer immediately.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You would need this:

```
file.flush()
# typically the above line would do. however this is used to ensure that the file is written
os.fsync(file.fileno())
```

Check this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush

> file.flush()
>   Flush the internal buffer, like stdio‘s fflush(). This may be a no-op on some file-like objects.
>   Note flush() does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk. Use flush() followed by os.fsync() to ensure this behavior.

**EDITED:** See this question for detailed explanations: [what exactly the python's file.flush() is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks everyone. I love how I can get a detailed answer in <10 mins.

Comment: @NauticalMile It's always such a pleasure to help and share. :)

Answer (score 5):

Does file.flush() after each write help?

Hannu

Answer (score 2):

This will write the file to disk immediately:

```
file.flush()
os.fsync(file.fileno())
```

According to the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync

> Force write of file with filedescriptor fd to disk. On Unix, this calls the native fsync() function; on Windows, the MS _commit() function.
>
> If you’re starting with a Python file object f, first do f.flush(), and then do os.fsync(f.fileno()), to ensure that all internal buffers associated with f are written to disk.