# Writing output of python print() to file appears after process is killed / finished

Tags: python, windows, file, file-io

I had several print() statements in my code. I want run the code overnight and have them write to file.
I tried redirecting output to file as:

```
python mycode.py >> log.txt
```

While python process is running, I cannot see anything written to file. When I kill the process and open the log file, I find the output in it.

Similar behavior was seen when I explicitlys specified file handle in the every print statement:

```
output_file = open('log.txt','w')
print('blablabla', file=output_file)
```

How can I make `print` to write the file immediately? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing your changes right away because in some cases, due to buffering, changes made to a file may not show until you close the file.

To save changes without closing, please, refer to this page [Can I save a text file in python without closing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756329/can-i-save-a-text-file-in-python-without-closing-it)

Comment: Does it mean I have to call `output_file.flush()` after every `print()` call?

Comment: Not necessary after **every** print. Changes are accumulating and you only need to `flush` it when you want it.

Comment: Yess thats correct, that solves problem to some extend. Seems thats how all python file APIs behave, right? Every time we flush or close, its written to disk. What about `os.fsync(file.fileno())`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and tell me if it updates, immediately or not. I'm always using this syntax in **PyCharm**. I hope it works with u, too.

**If you want to insert bunch of data one at time**.

```py
with open("log.txt", 'w') as test:
    print ("hello world!", file=test)
```

**If you want to insert data into `.txt`, then do some process, then back again to add more data to the `.txt`**

```py
test = open("log.txt", 'w')
print ("hello world!", file=test)
#==== Do some processes ====
print("This's the end of the file")
test.close()
```

Comment: This will open-close file every time

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem write?

Comment: This will close after you finish editing because in the syntax you wrote, you don't have a close clause at the end of it, so that the file predicts from you to write more until you done the complaining. `with open` is better because it gives you the ability to write the bulk of code at a time executed at time, too. If you want to initialized your `open` function at do some xode then back to adding something else. You've to add `close()` at the end.

Comment: I will attach what i explained into my answer.