# How to flush to disk without sync?

Tags: python, linux, bash

When my program is running a config file is often saved via python scripts, however the system is frequently shut down unsafely. Any changes made to the config recently are not there at boot. A user must either shut down in the correct manner or wait a while for the config to save properly to disk. I have tried syncing when a user saves a config but the issue still occurs, any other ideas?

To call my python scripts I use clish, which basically is using bash. So in bash i make a call to sync.

```
<COMMAND name="copy running-config startup-config"
        help="Copy to startup configuration">
        <CONFIG operation="dump" file="/path/startup-config"/>
        <ACTION>
        sync
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>
```

Comment: Please show exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik edited in more information

Comment: @Paul: You need to show what happens in the python script i.e. how are you implementing sync?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik In between the action tags above is bash. So I call sync from bash. I suppose the python doesn't matter as I am not calling sync from there. http://code.google.com/p/klish/wiki/ACTION

Comment: Sync by itself will not work. You need to flush the file (`file.flush()`) first. Take a look at this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing

Comment: @JayanthKoushik thank you, will have a look :)