# Python "With open(file) as f" is not saving the content if intrupt in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, with-statement

I mostly use `with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:` for writing (reading as well). today I notice something weird.

I was crawling a site and there was normal pagination.

```
While True:
   # visit url, get/scrape data
   # save data in text file
   # find next link(pagination) 
   # loop till next url is available.
```

for saving data first I did use `with`

```
with open('data.txt','w') as f:
    While True:
       # visit url, get/scrape data
       f.write(some_scraped_data)
       # find next link(pagination)
       # loop till next url is available.
```

but when I run this script and if some exception occurred, this loop gets terminated and no data save in data.txt file

but when I do `f = open('data.txt','w')` then whatever data is crawled is saved(till exception occurred) even I didn't put f.close()

```
f = open('data.txt','w')
While True:
    # visit url, get/scrape data
    f.write(some_scraped_data)
    # find next link(pagination) til next url is available.
```

my question is how can we achieve same thing with `with`.  and I'm just curious where everybody recommends `with` for file handling and its not supporting this feature.

PS: I'm not so experienced in python. so if you find this question silly, I'm sorry

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), the use of 'with' will close the file correctly if an exception occurs, so that is a good approach.

However, you could try `f.flush()` to get the buffer written to disc. More on flush here: [what exactly the python's file.flush() is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing)