# Python saving data inside Memory? (ram)

Tags: python, file, memory, save

I am new to Python, but I didn't know this til yet.
I have a basic program inside a for loop, that requests data from a site and saves it to a text file
But when I checked inside my task manager I saw that the memory usage only increase? This might be a problem for me when running this for a long time.
Is it standard for Python to do this or can you change it?
Here is a what the program basically is

```
savefile = open("file.txt", "r+")
for i in savefile:
     #My code goes here
     savefile.write(i)
#end of loop
savefile.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python does not write to file until you call `.close()` or `.flush()` or until it hits a specified buffer size. This question might help you: [How often does python flush to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file)

Comment: Ahh, great, I just checked it and it was at 18MB and raising so that's why I thought that. Will look into flush, thank you sir!

Comment: Note that to have it flush to actual disk you may also have to call `os.fysnc()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing

Answer (score 3):

As @Almog said, Python does not write to the file immediately. Because of this, every line you write to the file gets stored into RAM until you use `savefile.close()`, which flushes the internal buffer and writes everything to the file. This would explain the extra memory usage.

Try changing the loop to this:

```
savefile = open('file.txt', 'r+')
for i in savefile:
    savefile.write(i)
    savefile.flush() #flushes buffer, saving RAM
savefile.close()
```

Comment: Great example, I love it, it looks like it is steady at 18mb so it's not that big of a deal. Through I don't understand why there is a buffer, it it because ram is much faster then a hdd so that it can write it all at once vs 1 by 1. Or is it because some files run really fast thus not allowing the hdd to keep up with the speed of the program?

Comment: @Uber - It's very inefficient to write to the disk every time you add a line. In all, it's better for the computer to wait and write everything at once.

Comment: Yeah I looked into it. I will keep it as-is as it doesn't go above 18.5mb. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a better Solution, in pythonic way, to this:

```py
with open("your_file.txt", "write_mode") as file_variable_name:
    for line in file_name:
        file_name.write(line)
        file_name.flush()
```

This code flushes the File for each line and after it's execution it closes the File thanks to the with-Statement