# How to print strings from a txt file in python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, io

Allright,i have this script, wich creates a .txt file, and is supposted to print the string from it. But it prints out nothing(just Process finished with exit code 0)
, have no idea why and i can't find the anwser,(i'm pretty new to programming so i might not just get the idea of how some statements work) also i use python3.4

```
import io
import _pyio
import sys
import os

file1 = open("karolo.txt","w")
file3 = open("karolo.txt","r")
file1.write("abcd\n")
file34 = file3.read()
print(file34)
```

Comment: try `file1.close()` before opening `file3` it for reading, the contents are not correctly written to the file until it has been closed, or maybe use a `io.StringIO` to write and read from it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply (Didin't think i'd get an anwser so fast), i did not know that nothing is really written into the file till it is closed, fixed the problem. Also, im new to stack overflow, is there a way i can mark this as solved ? Don't want to bother anybody when this is fixed already

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! The speed of response really depends on who is online but I lied just a little, it doesn't write to the file until it has been [flushed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing),and closing a file flushes it, just look at that link if you want a more in depth explanation. (;

Comment: Seems flushing is more useful than closing the file. Thanks. Anyways, i get that you just don't mark questions as solved here ?

Comment: oh right, I will post my answer as an answer then you can [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to read the data before it reaches the file (it is only in the internal buffer) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7127162/5827215) for info about flushing data out of internal buffer into the file.

```
file1 = open("karolo.txt","w")
file3 = open("karolo.txt","r")
file1.write("abcd\n")
file1.flush()
file34 = file3.read()
print(file34)

#remember to close the files when you are done with them!
file1.close()
file3.close()
```

also see the [bottom of this doc section](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) about ensuring files get closed using a `with` statement:

```
with open("karolo.txt","w") as file1, open("karolo.txt","r") as file3:
    file1.write("abcd\n")
    file1.flush()
    file34 = file3.read()

assert file1.closed and file3.closed
```