# Python Append Not Working

Tags: python, append

So most of this code is my own, apologies for the fact it is probably a mess and/or horribly written, but my question is why the lines

```
D = open("C:\\aPATH\\hPROC.txt", "a")
D.write("End")
```

aren't appending "End" at the bottom of the file whenever it is called.

```
import time

def replace_all(text, rps):
    for i, j in rps.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

def replacer():
    inf = "hScrape.txt"
    ouf = "hPROC.txt"
    A = open(inf, "r")
    B = open(ouf, "w")
    reps = {"Result Date:":"", "Draw Result:":"", "Bonus":"", "January":"", "February":"", "March":"", "April":"", "May":"", "June":"", "July":"", "August":"", "September":"", "October":"", "November":"", "December":"", "With Max Millions!":"", "2009":"", "2010":"", "2011":"", "2012":"", "2013":"", "2014":"", "2015":"", "2016":"", "2017":"", "2018":"", "30th":"", "29th":"", "28th":"", "27th":"", "26th":"", "25th":"", "24th":"", "23rd":"", "22nd":"", "21st":"", "20th":"", "19th":"", "18th":"", "17th":"", "16th":"", "15th":"", "14th":"", "13th":"", "12th":"", "11th":"", "10th":"", "9th":"", "8th":"", "7th":"", "6th":"", "5th":"", "4th":"", "3rd":"", "2nd":"", "1st":"", "\t":""}
    txt = replace_all(A.read(), reps)
    B.write(txt)
    A.close
    B.close

    D = open("C:\\aPATH\\hPROC.txt", "a")
    D.write("End")

    C = open("C:\\aPATH\\Result.txt", "w+")
    print("Completed Filtering Sequence")
    time.sleep(3)


    while True:
        B = open("hPROC.txt", "r")
        z = B.readline()
        print(z)
        if "End" in z:
            C.write("DN")
            break
        else:
            if z != "\n":
                if " " not in z:
                    if int(z) < 10:
                        C.write("0" + z)
                    else:
                        C.write(z)

replacer()
```

Comment: you have forgotton to do a `D.close()`

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo is the close going to affect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way Python's file buffering system works, when opening a file and appending to it, but not closing it or flushing it, the appended lines aren't necessarily written.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing) for additional information on what flush does.

Therefore, a solution to your code would simply be changing it to

```
D = open("C:\\aPATH\\hPROC.txt", "a")
D.write("End")
D.close()
```

additionally, if you intend to append more and thus close the file later, you could make that snippet

```
D = open("C:\\aPATH\\hPROC.txt", "a")
D.write("End")
D.flush()
```

(which leaves the file open, and flushes the internal buffer to the OS buffer).

Comment: `D.flush()` by itself may not flush all data, merely flush the internal buffer to the os buffer

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo thank you; I’ve edited my post accordingly!

Comment: _Thank you_. I'm running a script with a lot of computation, and was wondering why the script is progressing but no new lines were being written; this is the first answer I've found in the past hour that mentioned `flush`-ing the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to close the file with `D.close()`

the `close()` will close the file, and writes all data which may be lingering in buffers.

If you do not want to close the file, you need to "flush" twice, example

```
D.flush()
os.fsync(D.fileno())
```

For the later, please do an `import os`, this will flush the os buffer for this file.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I found so far is  as follows:

```
with open("your text file") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "your text to append" in line.rstrip('\r\n'):
           print("Exists!")
           break
    else:
        f.write("your text to append" + "\n")
```