# Requests.get function not retrieving any data. What's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Trying to loop through some license ids to get data from a [website](https://cares.myflfamilies.com/PublicSearch).  Example: when I enter id "E09OS0018" in the search box, I get a list of one school/daycare.  But when I type the following code in my python script (website link and arguments obtained from developer tools), I get no data in the file.  What's wrong with this `requests.get()` command?  If I should use `requests.post()` instead, what arguments would I use with the `requests.post()` command (not very familiar with this approach).

```
flLicenseData = requests.get('https://cares.myflfamilies.com/PublicSearch/SuggestionSearch?text=E09OS0018&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=e09os0018&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=contains&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5BignoreCase%5D=true&filter%5Blogic%5D=and')
openFile = open('fldata', 'wb')
for chunk in flLicenseData.iter_content(100000):
    openFile.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Have you checked whether ``flLicenseData.raise_for_status()`` contains an error?

Comment: What's the output of `f1LicenseData.status_code()`?

Comment: No error raised by flLicenseData.raise_for_status(). f1LicenseData.status_code() results in error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable".  Not sure why I get that error because flLicenseData type isn't 'int' (it is class 'requests.models.Response').  openFile.flush() also didn't result in anything meaningful, other that printing the license ID to the file.

Comment: OK, figured out.  For those looking for a solution, I used the following requests.post command instead: 
flLicenseData = requests.post('https://cares.myflfamilies.com/PublicSearch/Search?dcfSearchBox=E08BA0001')

Answer (score 0):

do `openFile.flush()` before checking the file's content.

Most likely, you are reading the file immediately before the contents are (Actually) written to the file.

There could be a lag between the contents writen to the file handler and contents actually transfered to the physical file, Due to the levels of buffers between the programming language API, OS and the actual physical file.

use `openFile.flush()` to ensure that the data is written into the file.
An excellent explanation of flush can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing).

Or alternatively close the open file with `openFile.close()` or use a context manager

```
with open('fldata', 'wb') as open_file:
   for chunk in flLicenseData.iter_content(100000):
         openFile.write(chunk)
```