# is it necessary to call flush method of file handler in python

Tags: python, file, flush

I saw a code where they were using file.flush(). so, i searched around and found [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing). I kind of understood why there's a flush method. In the answer which was marked as answer the following was written

> Typically you don't need to bother with either method, but if you're in a scenario where paranoia about what actually ends up on disk is a good thing, you should make both calls as instructed.

So, i was wondering, when we open  a file using context manager and write some text, and then when the code exits from this context manager, there might be a chance that the text might not have been written to the file? if yes, why not python does this internally when file.close() is called?  is it being done already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file objects in the `io` module (the ones you get from `open`) and everywhere else you'd expect in the stdlib always `flush` when they `close`, or rely on platform APIs that are guaranteed to do so.

Even third-party libraries are required to "close and flush the stream" on their [`close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) methods if they want their objects to be file objects.<sup>1</sup>

---

The main reason to call `flush` is when you're *not* closing the file yet, but some other program might want to see the contents.

---

For example, a lot of people write code like this:

```
with open('dump.txt', 'w') as f:
    while True:
        buf = read_off_some_thingy()
        f.write(buf.decode())
        time.sleep(5)
```

… and then they wonder why when they `cat dump.txt` or open it in Notepad or whatever, it's empty, or missing the last 3 lines, or cuts off in the middle of a line. That's the problem `flush` solves:

```
with open('dump.txt', 'w') as f:
    while True:
        buf = read_off_some_thingy()
        f.write(buf.decode())
        f.flush()
        time.sleep(5)
```

---

Or, alternatively, they're running the same code, but the problem is that someone might pull the plug on the computer (or, more likely nowadays, kill your container), and then after restart they'll have a corrupt file that cuts off in mid-line and now the perl script that scans the output won't run and nobody wants to debug perl code. Different problem, same solution.

---

But if you know for a fact that the file is going to be closed by some point (say, because there's a `with` statement that ends before there), and you don't need the file to be done before that point, you don't need to call `flush`.

---

You didn't mention `fsync`, which is a whole other issue—and a whole lot more complicated than most people thing—so I won't get into it. But the question you linked already covers the basics.

---

<sub>1. There's always the chance that you're using some third-party library with a file-like object that duck-types close enough to a file object for your needs, but isn't one. And such a type might have a `close` that doesn't `flush`. But I honestly don't think I've ever seen an object that had a `flush` method, that didn't call it on close.</sub>

Comment: from that other SO post, i understood that fsync will dump OS buffer to disk. is it more complicated than that?

Comment: One more situation i can think of is that, when people just use file.open(file_name) and add all the data but, forget to close the file!

Comment: @InAFlash Yes, because what does "to disk" mean? Does it actually wait for the physical encoding onto magnetic or optical or whatever data? Even if the OS _thinks_ it does, many disk interfaces lie (because it improves their benchmarks). macOS provides a special `F_FULLSYNC` to (usually) work around that, but it doesn't happen by default; some linux filesystems always do it, some don't; etc. And the workaround doesn't always work. And what if "disk" is actually a network share? And so on.

Comment: @InAFlash Yes, that definitely happens—that's pretty much why `with` was added to the language. But when you do that, you usually aren't calling `flush`…

Comment: i will look into fsync more. looks interesting.

Comment: @InAFlash See [here](https://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2005/Feb/msg00072.html), and… I can't find it, but there's a thread about whether a linux filesystem can return from fsync when it's committed a journal entry that could *almost* certainly be used to recover and replay the write if someone pulled the plug, or only when it's committed to the main storage.

Answer (score 2):

Python *does* flush the file when it's `.close()`d, which happens when the context manager is exited.

The linked post refers more to a scenario where you have, say, a log file that's open for a long time, and you want to ensure that everything gets written to disk after each write. That's where you'd want to `.write(); .flush();`.