# Saving a file without closing it in Python

Tags: python-2.7, file, file-writing, saving-data

Suppose I have a dictionary of files that I am iterating through. I am doing some with each file and then writing it to report (Note: not using the `csv` mod).

```
file_list = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']
report  = "C:/reports/report_%s"%(timestamp)
r = open(report, "w')
```

What happens if something happens in f3 that crashes the script before it finishes. I can use `try-catch` to handle for an error but I don't want to just close the report. Perhaps I want the script to continue. Perhaps there is a power failure while the script is running. Perhaps there are multiple `try-catch` statements and I don't want to close for each error.  Essentially, I just want to save the file without closing it on each iteration of the list, so that if a crash occurs, I can still retrieve the data written to the report up until that point. How can I do this? I cannot simply do `report.save()`, right? I thought about using `flush()` with `os.fsync()` as explained in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-the-pythons-file-flush-is-doing), but I am not 100% sure that's applicable to my scenario. Any suggestion on how to achieve my goal here?

```
try:
    ....do stuff...
    report.write(<stuff_output> + "\n")
    try:
        ....do more stuff....
        report.write(<stuff_output> + "\n")
    except:
        continue
    report.close()
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I was able resolve this issue by simply using `flush()` and `os.fsync()` within the correct scope and placing the `r.close()` outside of the try. So even if it tries and fails it passes or continues and at the end it closes:

```
try:
    for item in file_list:
        try:
            r.write("This is item: " + item + "\n")

        except:
            r.flush()
            os.fsync(r)
            continue

except Exception as e:
    pass

r.close()
```

This would always print `"This is item: f1", "This is item: f2", "This is item: f3"` to the report.