# Why is file.close() so slow, even when there is no buffering and/or file.flush() has already been called?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

```py
from time import perf_counter
t = perf_counter()
file = open('dummy', 'wb', buffering=0)
print('open', perf_counter() - t)
t = perf_counter()
file.write(bytes(16 * 1024 ** 2))
print('write 16MB', perf_counter() - t)
t = perf_counter()
file.flush()
print('flush', perf_counter() - t)
t = perf_counter()
file.close()
print('close', perf_counter() - t)
```

It output:

```
open 0.00242589320987463
write 16MB 0.010545279830694199
flush 1.0263174772262573e-06
close 0.033106833696365356
```

I think that should be caused by OS page cache, BUT python does not support O_DIRECT unless mmap is used, since O_DIRECT require memory alignment. https://bugs.python.org/issue5396

Thus I tried on a faster storage mounted on `/data`:

```py
open 0.001985272392630577
write 16MB 0.009873169474303722
flush 1.1473894119262695e-06
close 0.006200509145855904
```

System Information:

```
> uname -srvmpio
Linux 5.15.0-78-generic #85~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 17 09:42:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> cat /proc/mounts | grep '/ '
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
> cat /proc/mounts | grep '/data '
/dev/nvme0n1 /data ext4 rw,relatime,stripe=32 0 0
> uname -a
```

Comment: Use `oprofile` or another kernel profiler to figure this out (that one's for Linux, there are other choices elsewhere). There is no generic answer that's true on every system (you haven't even told us which OS you're running, much less which filesystem, mount flags, etc are active, and even that might not be enough to narrow it down; **really**, you need to actually measure where the time is going on the specific host where you're curious about behavior; then head to [UNIX.se] (or another venue appropriate to your actual OS) if interpretation of those measurements is unclear).

Comment: What's the point of calling and measuring flush() when you've specified buffering=0 ? Also, your results are going to be very specific to your platform. For example, using your code exactly as posted on my system close() runs in 0.00026s

Comment: Use `flush()` when `buffering=0` should be a no-op, but there might be some extraordinary behavior, so I measure it. Yes, my results are very specific to my platform, so I add some system information here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7127162/10678955