# NodeJS child_process spawn not returning live stdout

Tags: python, node.js, ipc, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to run something along the lines of this python script from a javascript file (in an `electron` project), and echo the output in real-time:

```py
import time

def main():
    print("Hello 1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello 2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello 3")

    return 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = main()
    print(f"result: {result}")
```

And I'm using the following Javascript code to execute the file:

```js
// ...

const child = spawn(runners[lang], commandArgs, {shell: true});
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Received data: ${data}`);
});
```

What I'm seeing though is all the output being printed out in one giant blob after the whole script finishes running, and not "Hello 1", etc. being sent to my javascript line-by-line. Basically, it seems that my `child.stdout.on` callback is only running once. Is there a specific reason for this, and how can I receive data in `child.stdout.on` as soon as `print` is called in the python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the expected output, you need to [*forcibly flush the `stdout` stream* in your python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127075/what-exactly-is-file-flush-doing). This can be done by adding `flush=True` argument.

```
import time

def main():
    print("Hello 1", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello 2", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello 3", flush=True)

    return 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = main()
    print(f"result: {result}", flush=True)
```

Alternatively you could launch the python interpreter with `-u` option. This will [*force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered*](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u). By doing so, you won't have to specify `flush=True` on every `print` function call.

```
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

const child = spawn("python", ["-u", "your_file_name.py"], {shell: true});
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Received data: ${data}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any way I could make Python's `print` function flush automatically? instead of having to specify `flush=True` in every call

Comment: @non See my edit. You could add `-u` option when you launch the python interpreter.